# Two USB folders appear when connecting Samsung Infuse USB

Tags: android

I am trying connecting my Samsung Infuse to MAC and Win7 Machines.  What I often see is a folder shows up after connecting that says NO NAME

It contains only a few folder ANDROID, DCIM, LOST.DIR, etc

Then a few minutes later another folder shows up also called NO NAME

So yes there are tow NO NAME, NO NAME folders on the desktop.

Now the second one seems to have all the folders.

Why is this?  Why do I have to wait a few minutes and only then see an identical folder that has all the directories?

Answer (score 2):

If samsung infuse is like my Galaxy S2, the reason that it appears as 2 disks is because of the way your internal memory of the device is handled.

For instance my Galaxy S2 is said to have 16 gb internal memory (before sd card). This is actually internally split into 2 :

- 2 gb of true internal memory
- the remaining is actually considered the SD card

It is the second partition that is appearing as your first folder.
When you connect an additional sd card, it shows up as your second folder.

So to wrap up the two folders are

- Lions share of internal memory
- Micro SD card connected by you